# How to insert year data type in mysql server using java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

i have the the sql schema on sql server i am trying to insert the values in the table but i am getting error when i am trying to insert **Year** data type in sql
I have parsed the string to year data type for example

```
double c=Double.parseDouble("2019.0");
int yt=(int) c;
Year business_year; 
business_year=Year.parse(String.format("%04d", yt));
String qq="INSERT INTO invoice_details VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(qq);
pstmt.setYear(1,business_year);
```

`pstmt.setYear(1,business_year);`  in this line i am getting the following error

> The method setDate(int, Date) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, Year).

could someone please help in it.

Comment: does `PreparedStatement` really has a method `setYear` - even error message is telling something else - anyway, the method `setDate` does not accept a `Year`, only a `Date` or subclass of it

Comment: @user15244370 No it doesn't how to do that? how to insert Year data type in sql

Comment: what exactly you want to store in Database? What is the column type?

Comment: @user15244370 column datatype in sql schema is Year i want to insert into the table

Comment: checking the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html) suggest it must be a `Date` (`setDate`) or short (`setShort`) - maybe even String is accepted (`setString`)

Comment: @user15244370 so how to insert in to the table? Year datatype

Comment: see last comment, or try `setObject` (maybe `setDate`  with `Date.valueOf(business_year.atDay(1))`)

Comment: how do we convert from Year data type to String ?

Comment: @Akina there is Year datatype

Comment: and i am still facing the issue

Comment: @Akina please go through this (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html)

Comment: Year to string is `business_year.toString()`  (but also try `set Date(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(business_year.atDay(1)))`, I've no MySql to test here)

Comment: @user15244370 its giving error when i am trying to insert the data in the "Date" data type

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I do not use MySQL. I did read the [doc for version 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/year.html).

Java offers the `Year` class. MySQL offers the [`YEAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/year.html) data type. By the way, contrary to what your Question implies, the SQL standard does *not* define a `YEAR` data type as far as I know.

You might be able to pass the Java object directly. Support for the `Year` class is *not* defined in JDBC 4.2. So such behavior would be an optional feature specific to your particular JDBC driver. If your driver did offer this, I would expect it to use the `PreparedStatement#setObject` and  `ResultSet#getObject` methods.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , Year.now() ) ;
```

And…

```
Year y = myResultSet.getObject( … , Year.class ) ;
```

If your JDBC driver does not offer that support for `Year`, [the doc for MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/year.html) says you should be able to pass either text or an integer. Here is example code for passing/receiving an integer.

```java
Year year = Year.of( 2020 ) ;
…
pstmt.setInt( 2 , year.getValue() );
```

…and:

```java
Year year = Year.of( rs.getInt( "year_" ) );
```

Regarding your code:

> `pstmt.setYear(1,business_year);`

…there is no `setYear` method on `PreparedStatement`. That code will not compile.

## Example app

Further down is the source code for an entire example app.

This example has commented-out code trying to use [`PreparedStatement#setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,java.lang.Object)) and [`ResultSet#getObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class)) in conjunction with the [`java.time.Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) class.

This code fails with a lack of support for `Year` class when run with this JDBC driver via Maven dependency:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.23</version>
</dependency>
```

…on MySQL 8 hosted on DigitalOcean.com as a managed database service.

The two key lines in this example app are marked with `// <-- java.time.Year not supported by this JDBC driver.`.

```java
package work.basil.example.mysqlstuff;


import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.*;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.Year;
import java.util.Objects;

public class App
{
    // Member fields.

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello world. " );
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - Starting demo method. " + Instant.now() );

        DataSource dataSource = this.configureDataSource();
        this.dropTable( dataSource );
        this.createTable( dataSource );
        this.insertRow( dataSource );
        this.dumpTable( dataSource );

        System.out.println( "INFO - Done with demo method. " + Instant.now() );
    }

    private void dropTable ( DataSource dataSource )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - `dropTable` method. " + Instant.now() );
        try ( Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() )
        {
            String sql = """
                         DROP TABLE IF EXISTS event_
                         ;
                         """;
            System.out.println( "sql:  \n" + sql );
            try ( Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() )
            {
                stmt.execute( sql );
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createTable ( DataSource dataSource )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - `createTable` method. " + Instant.now() );
        try ( Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() )
        {
            String sql = """
                         CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event_
                            ( 
                               id_ INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,  -- ⬅ `identity` = auto-incrementing integer number.
                               title_ VARCHAR ( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
                               year_ YEAR NOT NULL 
                             )
                         ;
                         """;
            System.out.println( "sql:  \n" + sql );
            try ( Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ; )
            {
                stmt.execute( sql );
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void insertRow ( DataSource dataSource )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - `insertRow` method. " + Instant.now() );
        String sql = """
                     INSERT INTO event_ ( title_ , year_ )
                     VALUES ( ? , ? )
                     ;
                     """;
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
        )
        {
            pstmt.setString( 1 , "zero" );
//            pstmt.setObject( 2 , Year.of( 2020 ) );  // <-- java.time.Year not supported by this JDBC driver.
            pstmt.setInt( 2 , Year.of( 2020 ).getValue() );
            pstmt.executeUpdate();

            pstmt.setString( 1 , "one" );
            pstmt.setInt( 2 , Year.of( 2021 ).getValue() );
            pstmt.executeUpdate();

            pstmt.setString( 1 , "two" );
            pstmt.setInt( 2 , Year.of( 2022 ).getValue() );
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void dumpTable ( DataSource dataSource )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - `dumpTable` method. " + Instant.now() );

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM event_ ;";
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ;
        )
        {
            System.out.println( "-------|  event_ table  |--------------------" );
            while ( rs.next() )
            {
                //Retrieve by column name
                int id = rs.getInt( "id_" );
                String title = rs.getString( "title_" );
//                Year year = rs.getObject( "year_" , Year.class );     // <-- java.time.Year not supported by this JDBC driver.
                Year year = Year.of( rs.getInt( "year_" ) );

                System.out.println( "id_=" + id + " | title_=" + title + " | year_=" + year );
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private DataSource configureDataSource ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - `configureDataSource` method. " + Instant.now() );

        com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource dataSource = Objects.requireNonNull( new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource() );  // Implementation of `DataSource` bundled with H2.
        dataSource.setServerName( "db-mysql-sfo3-422-do-user-8982-1.x.db.ondigitalocean.com" );
        dataSource.setPortNumber( 24_090 );
        dataSource.setDatabaseName( "defaultdb" );
        dataSource.setUser( "scott" );
        dataSource.setPassword( "tiger" );
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked by setting it to pstmt.setShort()

Comment: Did you try `setObject`? That is the current avenue by which we exchange *java.time* objects per JDBC 4.2 and 4.3. If if does work, I’d like to edit this Answer to say so definitely rather than speculatively. And if `setObject` does work, please state exactly what JDBC driver you are using, and what version.

Comment: yes when i will try i will let you know thank you