# Jdbc:Connection is returning null in my program what to do?

Tags: java, jdbc

am getting an exception as `java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)` because `con` is null, I don't know why as I have already added MySQL Connector jar file.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class Studentdao {

public static boolean insertStudenttoDB(Student st) {

    boolean f=false;
try {
Connection con =CP.createc();
//jdbc code
String q="insert into students(sname,sphone scity)values(?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement(q);
pstmt.setString(1,st.getStudentname());
pstmt.setString(2,st.getStudentcity());
pstmt.setLong(3,st.getStudentphone());

//execute
pstmt.executeUpdate();
f=true;

}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return f;
}
}
```

This is my connection program

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class CP {


static Connection con;
//load driver
public static Connection createc() {
    try {
Class.forName("com.sql.jdbc.Driver");

//creating connection
String user="mysql";
String password="mysql";
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student_manage";
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
     
}catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

 return con;        
}
}
```

Comment: What exception occurs before the NullPointerException?

Comment: yes,NullPointerException

Comment: Yes but what exception happens **before** the NullPointerException?

Comment: ClassNotfoundException

Comment: Are you sure the package `com.sql.jdbc.Driver` is correct? Also, you don't even need the `Class.forName` since the service API.

Comment: The exception occurs before nullpointerexception is ClassNotfoundException....but why I have already added mysqlconnector jar

Comment: MySQL is not `com.sql` but rather `com.mysql`. also, you don't need the `Class.forName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Incorrect class name

You appear to have an incorrect class name, if you are using the [Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connector-j-info.html) product as your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver).

[Section 3.6.1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html) of the *Connector/J* manual shows the use of `"com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"` versus your use of `"com.sql.jdbc.Driver"`. Here is their code example:

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
// Notice, do not import com.mysql.cj.jdbc.*
// or you will have problems!
public class LoadDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
            // broken Java implementations
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // handle the error
        }
    }
}
```

## `DataSource`

Note that your use of `Class.forName` is generally not needed in modern Java. The JDBC architecture was years ago revamped so that now drivers are automatically located and loaded using the [Java Service Provider Interface (SPI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface) technology.

I do suggest you make a habit of using a [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) to obtain connections rather than calling on the `DriverManager`. Using `DataSource` makes your code much more flexible. You will be able to switch JDBC drivers, add connection pooling, and externalize configuration info (server address, database name, user name, password, etc.) for deployment.

Usually your JDBC driver comes with a basic implementation of `DataSource`. Check the documentation for all the various options you can set, specific to your database (MySQL in this case).

For MySQL, I understand the implementation of `DataSource` currently provided in *Connector/J* is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource`. Caveat: I make regular use of *Postgres* & *H2*, not *MySQL*, so I may not be up-to-date.

See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66413760/642706) to another Question for source code of a full example of connecting and working with MySQL. Here are the parts relating to `DataSource` and `Connection`.

```java
    private DataSource configureDataSource ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - `configureDataSource` method. " + Instant.now() );

        com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource dataSource = Objects.requireNonNull( new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource() );  // Implementation of `DataSource` bundled with H2.
        dataSource.setServerName( "db-mysql-sfo3-422-do-user-8982-1.x.db.ondigitalocean.com" );
        dataSource.setPortNumber( 24_090 );
        dataSource.setDatabaseName( "defaultdb" );
        dataSource.setUser( "scott" );
        dataSource.setPassword( "tiger" );
        return dataSource;
    }
```

Early in the lifecycle of your app, instantiate and retain the `DataSource` object returned from that method. Remember, a `DataSource` holds only the configuration details; it is not an open resource itself, and need not be closed.

```java
DataSource dataSource = this.configureDataSource();
```

To open a connection, pass the `DataSource` to your method that wants to connect to the database.

```
private void dumpTable ( DataSource dataSource ) { … }
```

Here is a piece of that `dumpTable` method.

Notice the use of [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to automatically close the open resources in the order in which they were declared, even in case of failure with exceptions being thrown.

```java
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM event_ ;";
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;  //  Use the passed `DataSource` object to ask for a `Connection` object.
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ;
        )
        {
            …
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

here's the code I tried to connect java class with mysql. Make sure you have to add the required driver to your libraries.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
public class Server {
public static Connection getConnection()
{
try
{
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   String urls = "127.0.0.1";//you can even replace this with localhost
   String username = "yourusername";
   String password = "1234";
   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+urls+":3306/yourdb?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8", username, password);
   return conn;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}
```